# Occupy width from sibling of parent with CSS

Tags: html, css, sass

As per HTML5 tag semantics, I designed a web page. A basic structure of the HTML body is as follows

```
<nav class="nav-primary">
 <div class="heading-primary">
   <!-- Logo & links of webpage -->
 </div>
 <div class="nav-side">
   <!-- Left side navigation of the page -->
 </div>
</nav>
<section class="section-content">
  <!-- Contents of the web page -->
</section>
```

The end website should have a standard look as follows

[image]

I thought of semantics and wrote the left navigation panel (.nav-primary > .nav-side) inside the 'nav' element.

Is there any method by which I can structure the left navigation panel to take up a certain percent of width of section content (.section-content).

Like, I don't want the left navigation panel to be placed above the section content (*using fixed position or something*). It has to be placed left of the section content sharing the total width using the same HTML structure.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: defined above HTML will work as -  your nav bar will be divided into 2 parts - logo, and Nav, and under that  you will have you content section

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can combine the use of CSS-grid and `display:contents` (https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-display-contents) to achieve this by keeping the same HTML structure:

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  height:100vh;
  display:grid;
  grid-template-rows: 50px 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: 
    "header header"
    "side content";
}
nav.nav-primary {
  display:contents;
}
.heading-primary {
  grid-area:header;
  background:red;
}
.nav-side {
  grid-area:side;
  background:blue;
}
.section-content {
  grid-area:content;
  background:green;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <nav class="nav-primary">
    <div class="heading-primary">
      <!-- Logo & links of webpage -->
    </div>
    <div class="nav-side">
      <!-- Left side navigation of the page -->
    </div>
  </nav>
  <section class="section-content">
    <!-- Contents of the web page -->
  </section>
</body>
```