# Can CSS Grid fill a grid-area with a non-direct child of the grid container? Or an element outside the grid container?

Tags: angular, css, css-grid

For example, say I want to have 2 items on top of each other like a normal list item.

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="item1"></div>
  <div id="item2"></div>
</div>
```

This would work if I apply

```
#container {
    display: grid; 
    grid-template-areas: "item 1" "item 2";
}
#item1 { grid-area: "item1";}
#item2 { grid-area: "item2";}
```

My question is, can I use other content outside of the grid container to fill these grid areas? eg.

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="item1">
</div>
<div id="item2"></div>
```

or:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="inner-container">
        <div id="item1"></div>
        <div id="item2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am working with Angular components and parent templates and I'm hoping to have some way to display my HTML nicely inside of 1 component instead of making multiple components that need to communicate with each other via services and/or eventEmitters, etc.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: for the second example you can consider `display:contents`, check this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/53631887/8620333

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47929369/3597276

Answer (score 2):

From MDN:
"When you add display: grid to a grid container, only the direct children become grid items and can then be placed on the grid that you have created. The children of these items display in normal flow."
[Link to MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Subgrid)

So in your first option:

```
<div id="container">
<div id="item1">
</div>
<div id="item2"></div>
```

item 2 won't be affected by the container because it's outside of the "container" div tags.

In your second option:

```
<div id="container">
<div id="inner-container">
    <div id="item1"></div>
    <div id="item2"></div>
</div>
```

You need to use Subgrid, by making "inner-container" a grid container.